# CIFS mount get dropped Ubuntu VM using VMWare

Tags: cifs, vmware-workstation

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 VM using VWWare workstation 12.5.7 with Windows 7 Host OS with a cifs mount that gets mounted at powerup. Well the mount keeps getting dropped after the connection goes idle, ls into the directory just hangs, and the only way to get it to work is to restart the VM. I've been trying to get more data but I don't see anything useful in the kernel logs (maybe I'm not searching for the right string?) or the syslog located in /var/log

I also tried enabling logging in vmware-tools by adding logging in tools.conf located in /etc/vmware-tools, that showed nothing useful.

Cifs logging didn't show anything either, I followed the instructions here: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/LinuxCIFS_troubleshooting

Does anyone here have any suggestions about where to look? I'm not sure if it's a Networking issue in my LAN, or if it's a bug in vmware tools, or what.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of Samba you're trying to connect to, it can be specified when mounting the cifs share by adding it to `/etc/fstab`, like:

```
//your-server   /your/mount   cifs   vers=2.1
```

Or by specifying it with `-o vers=3.0` if mounting from the command line.

This can prevent some compatibility issues which results in a suddenly dropped connection. The `mount.cifs` manpage says about `vers=`:

**1.0** - The classic CIFS/SMBv1 protocol. This is the ***default***.
**2.0** - The SMBv2.002 protocol. This was initially introduced in Windows Vista Service Pack 1, and Windows Server 2008. Note that the initial release version of Windows Vista spoke a slightly different dialect (2.000) that is not supported.
**2.1** - The SMBv2.1 protocol that was introduced in Microsoft Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008R2.
**3.0** - The SMBv3.0 protocol that was introduced in Microsoft Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012.

Also, if the mount becomes unresponsive and “hangs” as you say, try to unmount it with the `-l` / `--lazy option` (e.g. `umount -l /your/mount`). From the manpage:

**Lazy  unmount.**  Detach the filesystem from the file hierarchy now, and clean up all references to this filesystem as soon as it is not busy anymore.  (Requires kernel 2.4.11 or later.)