# Disable SMB1.0 client? Force SMB2+?

Tags: networking, smb

Due to the threat of WannaCry / Petya, my organization has disabled any SMB1.0 on our Windows servers.

As a result, our Ubuntu servers / workstations are unable to to authenticate to devices with SMB1.0/CIFS disabled.

Is there a way to force Ubuntu to use SMB2 or greater to authenticate to Windows systems?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify what version to use when mounting, by adding e.g. `vers=3.0` to the mount in `/etc/fstab`. I just wrote an explanation about mounting with different versions here: [CIFS mount get dropped Ubuntu VM using VMWare](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930769/cifs-mount-get-dropped-ubuntu-vm-using-vmware/930819#930819).

Comment: Sorry if I worded things poorly. I'm not actually trying to mount a share, I'm trying to figure out why this: https://community.rapid7.com/message/28262 is happening.